# Infinity loop on NGRX dispatch

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I write a simple to ngrx project to test store, but I got the infinity loop
However I try to copy other example without loop.
Firstly, I define 2 class model as below:

```
export interface IBookRecords {
    id? : number;
    bookNumber?: string;
    guestID ? : number;
    guestName ? :string;
    bookdetails? : IBookDetail[];
}

export interface IBookDetail {
    id? : number;
    roomName?: string;
    noOfGuest?:number;
}
```

For action.ts , I write this

```
requestSingleRecord : createAction('[Booking] Load booking record'),
requestSingleRecordSuccess : createAction('[Booking] Load booking record', props<{booker: IBookRecords}>() )
```

For effect.ts , I write this

```
loadBookRecords1$ = createEffect(() => this.action$.pipe
        (
            ofType(appActions.requestSingleRecord),
            mergeMap(() => 
                this.rmservice.SingleBookRecord()
                    .pipe(
                        switchMap(booker => [
                            appActions.requestSingleRecordSuccess({ booker })])
                    )
            )
        )
    );
```

For reducer.ts , I write this

```
export interface IAppState {
    booker : IBookRecords
}
export const initialState: IAppState = {
    booker:{}
}

export const appReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(appActions.requestSingleRecordSuccess, (state, action) => ({
        ...state, booker :action.booker
    })),

    on(appActions.updaterecord, (state, action) => ({
        ...state,  booker :action.booker
    }))
);
```

for selector.ts , I write this

```
const selectBookRecordFeature = createFeatureSelector<IAppState>('booker');
export const selectBookRecordCs = createSelector (
    selectBookRecordFeature,
    (state : IAppState) => state.booker
);
```

Then, when I write  `this.store.dispatch(appActions.requestSingleRecord());`
on appcomponent under ngOnInit() function, it will get infinite loop

Can anyone advise ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have same action type for both requestSingleRecord and requestSingleRecordSuccess. It's get infite loop, try to change the action types something like

```
   requestSingleRecord : createAction('[Booking] Load booking record'),
   requestSingleRecordSuccess : createAction('[Booking] Load booking record sucess', props<{booker: IBookRecords}>() )
```